# Centre of masses of 2 bodies together

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, mass

If there's a system made up of 2 regular bodies (say a pickaxe: a uniform rod and a circular arc attached at one end), is it right to say that the centre of mass of the total body is just the "center of mass" of the centers of mass of the rod and arc individually?

If yes, why? and if not, why?

Comment: Yes.  Why should it be anything else?

Comment: Yes, it is... as long as you consider the whole mass of each sub-body located in their own CM

Answer (score 1):

The CM definition is:
$$
x_{CM}=\frac{\sum_{a=1}^{N}m_a x_a}{\sum_{a=1}^{N}m_a}
$$
Then you can consider two subsystems, let's say A containing the particles {1,2,...,M} and the B containing the particles {M+1,...,N}.
The original definition of the CM can be expressed as:
$$
x_{CM}=\frac{\sum_{a=1}^{M}m_a x_a+\sum_{a=M+1}^{N}m_a x_a}{\sum_{a=1}^{M}m_a+\sum_{a=M+1}^{N}m_a}=\frac{\frac{\sum_{b=1}^{M}m_b\sum_{a=1}^{M}m_a x_a}{\sum_{b=1}^{M}m_b}+\frac{\sum_{b=M+1}^{N}m_b\sum_{a=M+1}^{N}m_a x_a}{\sum_{b=M+1}^{N}m_b}}{\sum_{a=1}^{M}m_a+\sum_{a=M+1}^{N}m_a}= \frac{M_A x_{A,CM}+M_Bx_{B,CM}}{M_A+M_B}.
$$
In the last line I used the definition for the CM of the subsystems and the subsystems' masses.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct. What you're actually saying is:
$$\frac{ab+cd}{a+c}=\frac{a\frac{ab}{a}+c\frac{cd}{d}}{a+c}$$
Where a is mass of the rod, b is the coordinate of its center of mass, c is mass of the curved part, d is the coordinate of its center of mass. If you want to verify it, you can take a uniform rod of length l, find its center of mass, and break it into two parts in any ratio and then find the CM of rod by finding the parts' respective CMs. You will get the same answer.

Comment: you add $kg$ to $m$ in denominator, therefore your equation is invalid. What you probably meant was $\frac{ab+cd}{a+c}$, i.e. denominator part should reflect total mass of body.

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas yep, my bad. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Because the definition of center of mass is defined as

$$\vec r_{cm} = \frac{\sum_i m_i \vec r_i}{\sum_i m_i}$$

If the masses were all equal, this would be the "average" position of the masses. If not, it is a weighted average. This makes sense. If you have two masses, and one is twice as heavy as the other, you get the same center of mass as for three equal masses.

In your case of rod and circular arc, the system is a collection of atoms.

$$\vec r_{sys} = \frac{\sum_{rod+ arc} m_i \vec r_i}{M_{rod+ arc}}$$

Individually, you have

$$\vec r_{rod} = \frac{\sum_{rod} m_i \vec r_i}{M_{rod}}$$
and
$$\vec r_{arc} = \frac{\sum_{arc} m_i \vec r_i}{M_{arc}}$$

So

$$\vec r_{sys} = \frac{M_{rod} \vec r_{rod} + M_{arc} \vec r_{arc}} {M_{rod}+ M_{arc}} = \frac{\sum_{rod} m_i \vec r_i + \sum_{arc} m_i \vec r_i}{M_{rod}+ M_{arc}}$$

You can see the two ways of calculating $\vec r_{sys}$ give the same result.

Comment: This can be extended to a "perforated" shape (e.g. a rectangular plate with a few circular holes in it) by combining the various regular shapes as above, but assigning negative masses (equal to the missing mass) to the holes

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of [my answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/791731/148184) to a related center-of-mass question
( [Subtraction of Masses in Centre of Mass Formula Proof](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/742568/subtraction-of-masses-in-centre-of-mass-formula-proof) ), I offer a proof starting with a small number of particles (not requiring summation notation, to emphasize the main idea).

For simplicity, consider four point masses in 1-dimension. Generalize as you wish to more complicated situations.

Define $x_{12}$ as the center of mass of $m_1$ at $x_1$ and $m_2$ at $x_2$ by
$$m_{12} x_{12} = m_1 x_1 + m_2 x_2,$$ where $m_{12}=m_1 +m_2$, and similarly for other pairs.

Similarly,
define $x_{1234}$ as the center of mass of $m_1$ at $x_1$ , $m_2$ at $x_2$, $m_3$ at $x_3$, and $m_4$ at $x_4$ by
$$m_{1234} x_{1234} = m_1 x_1 + m_2 x_2+m_3 x_3+m_4 x_4,$$ where $m_{1234}=m_1 +m_2+m_3+m_4= m_{12}+m_{34}$, which we have expressed in terms of one partition of the 4 masses.

Now note that
\begin{align}
m_{1234} x_{1234}
 &= (m_1 x_1 + m_2 x_2) + (m_3 x_3+ m_4 x_4)\\
 &= (m_1+m_2)\frac{(m_1 x_1 + m_2 x_2)}{(m_1+m_2)} 
+ (m_3+m_4)\frac{(m_3 x_3+ m_4 x_4)}{(m_3+m_4)}\\
 &= (\qquad\quad\ m_{12}x_{12}\qquad\quad\ ) +  (\qquad\quad\  m_{34}x_{34}\qquad\quad\ )\\
\end{align}
implies
\begin{align}
x_{1234}
 &= \frac{ m_{12}x_{12}  +   m_{34}x_{34}}{m_{12}+m_{34}}\\
\end{align}
Generalize as you wish to more complicated situations.

Answer (score -1):

Consider the equation for the x-coordinate, X, of the center of mass:
MX = $\sum_{i=1}^n(m_i x_i)$, where M is the total mass and the sum is over the product of all the individual particles and their x-coordinates. That sum can be broken up into the sum over the particles in the first body and the particles in the second body: $\sum_{i=1}^j(m_i x_i)$ + $\sum_{i=j+1}^n(m_i x_i)$ assuming the first body has j particles. But $\sum_{i=1}^j(m_i x_i)$ = $M_1 X_1$ and $\sum_{i=j+1}^n(m_i x_i)$ = $M_2 X_2$ where $M_1 X_1$ is the total mass of the first body time its center of mass x-coordinate, etc. for the second body. Thus we have:
X = ($M_1 X_1$ + $M_2 X_2$)/M as you asked.

Comment: It would be useful if the downvote to an answer is explained.